# NSDictionary: Comparing NSDictionaries

Tags: objective-c, data-structures, nsmutablearray

There are two of files.  Lets call them `fileOne` and `fileTwo`

Each has several NSMutableDictionary properties with identical names.  To list a few:

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSMutableDictionary * lunchStartTimeObject;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSMutableDictionary * lunchLocationNameObject;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSMutableDictionary * lunchLocationAddressObject;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSMutableDictionary * activity1NameObject;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSMutableDictionary * activity1StartTimeObject;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSMutableDictionary * activity1LocationNameObject;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSMutableDictionary * activity1CommentsFieldObject;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSMutableDictionary * activity1LocationAddressObject;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSMutableDictionary * activity2NameObject;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSMutableDictionary * activity2StartTimeObject;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSMutableDictionary * activity2LocationNameObject;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSMutableDictionary * activity2CommentsFieldObject;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSMutableDictionary * activity2LocationAddressObject;
```

I would like to compare the dictionaries with the same name in the two files by calling the method below (or something similar):

```
-(NSMutableDictionary *)cellColorForChanges:(NSMutableDictionary *)newdictionary :(NSMutableDictionary *)oldDictionary;
{
    if(![newdictionary isEqualToDictionary:oldDictionary])
    {
        [newdictionary  setValue:@"UIColor yellowColor" forKey:@"cellColor"];
    }
    return newdictionary;
}
```

I'm trying avoid writing code for each NSMutableDictionary manually.  Is there a way to avoid the following:

```
if(![fileOne.lunchStartTimeObject isEqualToDictionary:fileTwo.lunchStartTimeObject])
{  
    fileOne.lunchStartTimeObject setValue:@"UIColor yellowColor" forKey:@"cellColor"]; 
}
```

I'm having trouble figuring out the most efficient way to accomplish the above.  Is it somehow possible to send each dictionary to a method and get back the dictionary (updated with another key, if it's not equal)? Or what I'm trying to avoid is unavoidable?

Comment: Well, you eventually have to compare dictionaries.  Thankfully, isEqualToDictionary does an item-by-item compare, so you don't have to code that.  You can, of course, avoid some extra coding by placing the dictionaries into arrays and writing code to iterate through the arrays and compare, vs having to write a separate compare for each.  However, this won't be any more "efficient", execution-wise.  You can also compare hash values first, knowing that a mismatched hash means not equal.  But this only pays off if most will not match -- you still have to compare to assure "equal".

Answer (score 0):

You are running into this problem because you are not abstracting your objects sufficiently. It seems to me that your property list above is ridiculously redundant. Even the simple code code you provided is hardly readable.

Try to think of your problem in a more conceptional way. Try to think of objects that could encapsulate the functionality you are looking for.

Looking at your properties you probably want a class like this

```
@interface Activity : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDate *startTime;
@property (nonatomic, strong) Location *location;

-(BOOL)isEqualToActivity:(Activity*)activity;

@end
```

Maybe you need a location class that stores more information about a location; perhaps you could use even more fields like firstName, lastName; maybe you need a `type` (enum or string) property that tells what kind of activity it is, etc. -- you get the idea.

As indicated, you could write your own comparison method where you could tweak for allowing more or less strict capital or small letters, number formats etc.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I like to use Dictionaries to store text & detailText info and store them into an array.  Then I put the arrays in sectionArray.  Next, I enumerateObjectsUsingBlock over the sectionArray and if array.count>1, I display them:     cell.textLabel.text = [cellManagedObject valueForKey:@"text"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [cellManagedObject valueForKey:@"detailText"];  I'm sure there is a better way to accomplish this, but for now this is working for me.  Do you a technique to display a UITableViewController  that displays cells based on User provided Data?

Comment: Sections at times are empty; Section Display Order changes; not all cells will have cell.detailTextLabel.text.

Comment: The problems you raise in your comments (how to populate a table view) are entirely different. This is about adequate datasource methods, not how you design your classes.